# Android Unit Testing using Navigation Architecture

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

i am using Android Navigation Component which has 1 activity named as **Authentication Activity** which contains 3 fragments named **SplashFragment**, **Login Fragment**, **OTP Fragment**.

I want to do Unit Testing for Login Fragment which contains different fields like Mobile Number, Name, Email, State dropDown.

Please help me out how to write Unit test cases for Mobile number field, Name, email. I had attached sample unit test code of mine, gradle dependency.

Framework tried:- **Mockito**, **Espresso**, **Roboelectric**

Thanks in advance.

```
@Test
fun vmInitialization() {
    val state1 = State("DL", "Delhi")
    val state2 = State("UP", "Uttar Pradesh")
    val list: ArrayList<State> = ArrayList()
    list!!.add(state1)
    list!!.add(state2)
    val bundle = Bundle().putParcelableArrayList("stateList", list as ArrayList<Parcelable>)
    launchFragment(R.id.loginFragment, bundle as Bundle)
    val navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph_auth)
    val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<LoginFragment>()
    navController.setViewModelStore(ViewModelStore())
    scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    }
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btn_proceed)).perform(ViewActions.click())
    val navGraph = navController.navigatorProvider.navigation(
        id = R.id.nav_graph_auth,
        startDestination = R.id.otpFragment
    ) {
    }
    navController.setGraph(navGraph, null)
    scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        assertNotNull(fragment)
        assertThat(fragment).isNotNull()
        assertThat(fragment.savedStateViewModel).isNotNull()
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies:-

```
debugImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.3.0-alpha06"
debugImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.2.0"
debugImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.2.0"
debugImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.2.0")
debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-beta01")
debugImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.1"
debugImplementation('androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0') {
    // exclude androidx.test:core while fragment_testing depends on 1.1.0
    exclude group: 'androidx.test', module: 'core'
}
```

Comment: Hi Developer's.... Any Update on this issue??

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by what you mean by unit testing/unit test case and OTP Fragment. But if you are going to have a `Login Fragment`. Your app should have an API so that you can store your `User data` easily. Unless you know sql, I suggest you use Firebase Realtime Database/ Firebase Authentication since its beginner friendly.

Here is a link of what it would feel like with Firebase. (https://youtu.be/NhEU7G-KrEI)